# Disable wpautop on Shortcode attributes

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop

I have a shortcode which accepts basic HTML tags as shortcode attribute.

When this shortcode is used in the shortcode block i.e within `<!-- wp:shortcode -->` then unbalanced `<p>` tags are added to the shortcode attribute.

If it is used normally, then no `<p>` tags are added.

Are there any workarounds which can be done to avoid this issue ?

```
function abcd_shortcode( $atts ){
    print_r( $atts );
}
add_shortcode('abcd', 'abcd_shortcode');
```

[image]

Output (notice the `</p>` and `<p>` tags added for no reason in the second array)

```
Array
(
    [html] => <h4>Hey</h4>Outside
)

Array
(
    [html] => </p>
<h4>Hey</h4>
<p>Inside
)
```

Comment: This really isn't how shortcode attributes are supposed to work. If you want to accept HTML in a shortcode, use an enclosing shortcode: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/enclosing-shortcodes/

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes I'm aware of that. But any idea why there is a discrepancy between normal and when used inside the shortcode block ?

Comment: @JacobPeattie The idea is that the attribute would accept a basic HTML which the shortcode needs it internally. I agree it is not ideal, but curious to fix it since it works sometimes.